# How to search comments exclusively in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm interested in only searching comments in VSCode. Is this possible? Specifically, I would like to search for instances of `()` in comments only.

Comment: what is your comment start chars

Answer (score 0):

Supposed it's not a block comment, you could try matching it with a regex.

```
# line comment
or
// line comment

/* 
block comment
*/
```

Searching using regex can be easily achieved by clicking the icon with two stars on the right of the search bar.

[image: Search bar]

If `#` is your comment character, you could use `# *yourInstanceHere`.